# Lazyeval over-writing dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Not quite understanding what "lazyeval" is, I was trying to install and run the package to use dplyr within a function.

When I ran

```
library(lazyeval)
```

I got the error message:

```
Error in library(lazyeval) : there is no package called 'lazyeval'
```

even after successfully installing.

Now, though, when I try to run any standard dplyr script, I get the following error message:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'lazyeval'
```

It's as if the lazyeval has over-written dplyr, but I can't actually use lazyeval.

Has anyone run into this issue? If so, how did you resolve?

Some info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] scales_0.2.4     gridExtra_0.9.1  ggplot2_1.0.0    forecast_5.4    
 [5] timeDate_3010.98 reshape2_1.4     xts_0.9-7        zoo_1.7-11      
 [9] lubridate_1.3.3  dplyr_0.4.1      plyr_1.8.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1   colorspace_1.2-4 DBI_0.3.1        digest_0.6.4    
 [5] fracdiff_1.4-2   gtable_0.1.2     lattice_0.20-29  magrittr_1.0.1  
 [9] MASS_7.3-35      memoise_0.2.1    munsell_0.4.2    nnet_7.3-8      
[13] parallel_3.1.2   proto_0.3-10     quadprog_1.5-5   Rcpp_0.11.1     
[17] stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.2      tseries_0.10-32
```

When I run .libPaths(), I get two directories:

```
[1] "C:/Users/MTULLA/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library"
```

In the first, I can find both dplyr and lazyeval, both with .dll files. In the second, I can't find either

Comment: Post some `sessionInfo()` and maybe `.libPaths()`, and confirm that a directories called `lazyeval` and `dplyr` (with files in them!) are in one of your libraries.

Comment: @Gregor, I edited the original question with those items...

Comment: and just an update: It throws the error when I try to use the "group_by" function... I deleted the folder, and I'm still running into the problem...

Comment: Delete both package folders and reinstall?

Comment: You should try updating your R version to the newest and then updating the packages. Might not be strictly related to the issue but end up solving it.

Comment: @Gregor - that worked! Thank you...Molx, I'm sure the same would work as well

Answer (score 2):

I also got this message when running the lesson 1 of Getting and Cleaning Data on Swirl.

> Package ‘dplyr’ loaded correctly!
>
> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘lazyeval’

Reinstalling packages also didn't work

It was solved by updating my R version using the {installr} package

Answer (score 1):

It can be resolved by installing the package with all the dependencies, using:

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

It will install others like lazyeval, knitr etc. Worked for me to solve the 
Error in `loadNamespace(name): there is no package called ‘lazyeval’` issue.