# error loading packages R, almost all packages

Tags: r, package

Today I opened R as usual and loaded all my libraries as usual, however most of my packages report an error now!

For example

```
library(ggmap)

> library(ggmap)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘lazyeval’
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
```

I have never had this error before or encountered the package 'lazyeval'.

The story is similar for many other packages:

> library(lubridate)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lubridate’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>    there is no package called ‘stringi’

Somehow it seems that I need to install all packages again?

Any idea what happened? As far as I know nothing has changed since I used R yesterday..

Comment: Might be similar to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393983/lazyeval-over-writing-dplyr)

Comment: My problem is with many other packages as well.. even I tried to load the Installr package as suggested in that post and I get: > library(installr)
Loading required package: stringr
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘stringi’

Comment: have you upgraded `R` and / or packages recently? what does `sessionInfo()` give?

Comment: I have just tried to update all my packages to see if it helps, with no effect. This is my version: R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: I have now solved the problem for now by installing those packages reported missing...